# How to correctly implement jquery

Tags: jquery, implementation

I am having a hard time implementing the code above. I was hoping someone could point me in the right direction. I cannot get the images to scale where they maintain ratio while filling the whole box. So I am trying to use javascript to pick up on the dimensions. My problem is that I am new with java and I think I am implementing it wrong somehow. Can someone please tell me what I am doing wrong.

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="_jquery/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>

</head>

<body>
<div class="gallery_item">
  <article class="piece">
    <div class="piece-image">
     <figure> <img src="_img/prod/22.jpg" alt="asdf"> </figure>
      </div>
      <section class="piece-title">
        <div  class="piece-title-text">
          <h6>Title of piece</h6>
          <h5>by Artists Name</h5>
          <p><img src="_img/magnifyingGlass.png" width="283" height="417" alt="enlarge"></p>
        <p>ENLARGE</p>
        <h3>$600 - $1200</h3>
        <p>View details of this print</p>
      </div>
    </section>
  </article>
</div>

<script>$(".piece_image img").each(function(){
var thisWidth = $(this).width();
var thisHeight = $(this).height();

if(thisWidth > thisHeight) {
$(this).css("width", "auto");
$(this).css("height", "100%");
} else if(thisHeight > thisWidth) {
$(this).css("width", "100%");
$(this).css("height", "auto");
}

}); </script>


---css---
.piece-image {
width: 100%;
float: left;
position:relative;
display: block;
height: 200px;}

.piece-image figure {
display: block;
position: relative;
text-align: center;
vertical-align:middle;
margin: 0 auto;
height: 200px;
overflow: hidden;
top: 0;
z-index: 1;}

.piece-image figure img {
vertical-align:middle;
position:absolute;
margin: auto;
top: 0;
left: 0;
right: 0;
bottom: 0;
z-index:1;}
```

Comment: Why are you loading two different jQuery versions?

Comment: You query `.piece_image`, but your class name is `piece-image`

Comment: Question title is misleading.

Comment: "My problem is that I am new with java and I think I am implementing it wrong somehow" - Java and JavaScript are completely two different languages.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way of doing this is to use an image resizer, they are quite easy to use and you'll also saves bandwidth if you are resizing large images, download [Thumber](http://code.google.com/p/phpthumbmaker/wiki/ThumberWiki):

Here is how you use it:

```
http://yourserver.org/thumber.php?img=images/abc.png&h=200
```

You can also use w (width) as the parameter, or both, it will never stretch the image.